# generic irreduciblity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose we have a proper morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $0\in Y$.  If the fiber $f^{-1}(0)$ is irreducible and reduced, is the set $\{y\in Y|f^{-1}(y) \text{ is irreducible and reduced}\}$ open?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57802/what-properties-define-open-loci-in-families

Comment: That is false.  Let $Y$ be $\mathbb{A}^1_k = \text{Spec}\ k[t]$.  Let $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ denote $\text{Proj}\ k[u,v]$.  Let $X$ be the closed subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^1_k\times_k \mathbb{P}^1_k$ with defining equation $tuv=0$.  Let $f:X\to Y$ be the projection.  The fiber of $f$ over $t=0$ is $\mathbb{P}^1$, which is irreducible and reduced.  Every other fiber is reducible, consisting of two closed points, $[u,v] =[1,0]$ and $[u,v]=[0,1]$.

Comment: Hey, Jason, i just saw your answer here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/217488/is-the-locus-of-points-which-have-irreducible-fibers-constructible#comment564251_217488

Comment: Hey, Jason, i just saw your answer here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/217488/is-the-locus-of-points-which-have-irreducible-fibers-constructible#comment564251_217488 and asked the following question: if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is proper and flat, can we always do normalization such that we can asssume X and Y are normal and f is still proper flat.  I am a little confused by this, since when we normalize $Y$ to &Y^\prime&, then base change $X$ to $X^\prime:=X \times_{Y}Y^\prime$, $X^\prime$ is not nessasary normal, if we normalized $X^\prime$, then the flatness can not keep.

Answer (score 1):

I am just posting my comment as an answer so that this question will not continue unanswered.  Without further hypothesis, the result is false.  If $f$ is open, then there is a positive answer in  the link Daniel Loughran provides, [What properties define open loci in families?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57802/what-properties-define-open-loci-in-families)  Without the flatness hypothesis, there are many counterexamples.  One counterexample has $Y= \mathbb{A}^1_k = \text{Spec}\ k[t]$, and has $X= \text{Zero}(tuv) \subset \mathbb{A}^1_k \times \mathbb{P}^1_k$, where $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ denote $\text{Proj}\ k[u,v]$.